# Bitemporal data and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, rdbms, b-tree

We have developed a Bitemporal schema and a perl library which takes care of making IUD on Bitemporal form. All the data is in SQL Server 2008 and the entire system is always busy with too many readers and writers (writing in bitemporal form).

**Will it scale/not cause deadlock's since SQL server's internal indexing is B+ tree based ?**

We have had a lot of deadlock(s) in the past in the non bitemporal system which is not happening too frequently nowadays after we added better indexes, added **NOLOCK, ROWLOCK** judiciously.

In Bitemporal form, all readers and writers mostly run range queries. We believe that will add more to the deadlock problem considering the internal indexing is a B+ tree.
Shouldn't **Spatial indexing** prove better here ?

Is my assumption right ?
Any ideas ?